# Spring Object Creation and @autowiring annotation

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am new to spring

I can understand that @Autowiring is used to create the object.I have seen a sample project and code like this

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeManager employeeManager;
```

but I can see that EmployeeManager is an interface

```
public interface EmployeeManager {
    public void addEmployee(EmployeeEntity employee);
    public List<EmployeeEntity> getAllEmployees();
    public void deleteEmployee(Integer employeeId);
}
```

But in java we can't create an object for interface right.So how does this work .Slightly Confused

Can you please explain?

Comment: Autowire does not create anything: it instructs your Spring container to find a component of declared type and set it in marked field. You still have to both write implementation and register it with Spring.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an implementation for that class. Let's say EmployeeManagerImpl. So when spring finds the statement,

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeManager employeeManager;
```

It looks in the spring context and see if you have defined any beans (of concrete type) which are of type EmployeeManager. If it finds exactly one bean of that type, it takes that bean and puts it in the property employeeManager.

When we say defining beans, there are two ways to do this.

Either the xml way,

```
<bean class = "org.sample.EmployeeManagerImpl />
```

Or the annotation way

```
@Component
public class EmployeeManagerImpl {
}
```

During app start up, spring finds all the xml files and scans all the classes for @Component annotations, creates the beans and stores them in spring context. As part of that start up, when it encounters some class (which by the way is supposed to be a bean) which has Autowired annotation, it tries to inject a bean (which is nothing but an instance of a class) into this property.

Answer (score 1):

When you `@Autowire` any interface, spring searches for the bean that is mapped with the autowired interface and instantiates(`creates a singleton instance`) the concrete class/implementation accordingly. These beans are defined in your servlet-config whether done via XML or Java code.